# How do I enable the keyboard whilst in tablet mode?

Tags: hp, tablet

I have a HP Pavilion X360 laptop that can turn into a laptop,

I am currently using POP!_OS.

I have tried making a libinput file.. Enabling drivers.. They don't work.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more elaborate about what you did? Did you search for any tutorials on how to make this work?

Comment: Yes, they didnt work